# Add a dictionary to a key

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I am trying to set up a dictionary to look like this:

```
my_dict = {
    'USA': 
        {
            'Count': 10, 
            'Total': 1000
        },
    'UK' : 
        {
            'Count': 1, 
            'Total': 200
        },
    'South Africa': 
        {
            'Count': 20, 
            'Total': 240
        }
}
```

output:

> {'USA': {'Count': 10, 'Total': 1000}, 'UK': {'Count': 1, 'Total': 200}, 'South Africa': {'Count': 20, 'Total': 240}}

So that later I can get an average of a given country, by doing say

`usa_avg = my_dict["USA"]["Total"] / my_dict["USA"]["Count"]`

Manually, the above works.

But if I try to add a country, say `Canada`, with

```
my_dict["Canada"]["Count"] = 1
```

I get

> KeyError: 'Canada'

Comment: You have to do `my_dict['Canada'] = {}` first.  Or better yet use a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)

Comment: @PatrickHaugh - Aha!! Thanks! I was able to do it in my iteration, like you suggested. `my_dict["Canada"] = {'Count': 100, 'Total':20}`.  If you like, turn that into an answer :D  ([This page](https://www.quora.com/In-Python-can-we-add-a-dictionary-inside-a-dictionary-If-yes-how-can-we-access-the-inner-dictionary-using-the-key-in-the-primary-dictionary) helped too, I just found it)

Comment: @PatrickHaugh - Hm, then how do I loop through just the countries? Are they a `key` of `my_dict`?  I tried `for itm in my_dict.items(): print(itm.keys())` but get the `'tuple' has no attribute 'keys'`. error

Comment: Either `for country in my_dict.keys()` or `for country, data in my_dict.items()`, depending on whether you also need the values. Read more about `dict` views here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects